# different solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

With the following differential equation:

$$4x \cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-4$$

I found $$y=\frac{2+2Cx}{1-Cx},$$

to be a solution, but I also found:

$$y=2\tanh\left(-\frac{1}{2}\ln|4x|+C\right)$$

to be a solution, and I checked by differentiating. What am I doing wrong? One function isn't defined for $x=0$ and they are absolutely different. Are they two different functions satisfying the differential equation? (not differing only by a constant).

Comment: I checked the first solution and it looks correct to me. Did you check if both solutions are equivalent ?

Comment: When I put them both in Desmos for example, they look different and don't coincide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not that different. Use the properties of logarithm and the definition of $\tanh$. For simplicity $C=\ln D$.

$$-\frac 12 \ln|4x|+C=\ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{|4x|}}+\ln D=\ln \frac{D}{\sqrt{|4x|}}\\\tanh\ln \frac{D}{\sqrt{|4x|}}=\frac{e^{\ln \frac{D}{\sqrt{|4x|}}}-e^{-\ln \frac{D}{\sqrt{|4x|}}}}{e^{\ln \frac{D}{\sqrt{|4x|}}}+e^{-\ln \frac{D}{\sqrt{|4x|}}}}\\=\frac{\frac{D}{\sqrt{|4x|}}-\frac{\sqrt{|4x|}}{D}}{\frac{D}{\sqrt{|4x|}}+\frac{\sqrt{|4x|}}{D}}=\frac{D^2-|4x|}{D^2+|4x|}$$

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance, but the functions are still different (they are not exactly the same), but are they still both solutions despise differing not only by a constant?

Comment: Let $D=2i/\sqrt K$, so $D^2=-4/K$. Then divide everywhere by that factor.

Comment: Thank you! Are both solutions correct then? The solution with the hyperbolic tangent is not defined in x=0, but after some algebra it gives the other solution. How do I know I found the correct "form"? Sorry, but that really confuses me that different method bring me to functions that are not exactly the same (in their domain for example).

Comment: Both solutions are OK. The difference is based on the way you solve the problem. If you have a certain approach you might introduce some restrictions or extra solutions. You need to post the entire approach, step by step, to see where this happens

Comment: Thank you again, you really help me! My question is the following then, If I solve a differential equation in method A, and get some function without setting a restriction on any values of x in the way, and then solve in method B while excluding x=0 because it includes $\ln(x)$ for examle, which isn't defined for x=0, doesn't it make my solution only partial?

Comment: Correct. But when you solved with method B, you artificially excluded x=0.  The same way you excluded $1/C$ from the first solution